# missing in type '{ items: IProduct[]; }' but required in type

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hi I have problem with import a class CollectionView I got an error

> (alias) class CollectionView import CollectionView Property
> 'handlerItemClicked' is missing in type '{ items: IProduct[]; }' but
> required in type 'Readonly'.ts(2741) Products.tsx(36, 3):
> 'handlerItemClicked' is declared here. No quick fixes available

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import { CollectionView } from './CollectionView';
    import './App.css';
    import { MyButton } from './MyButton';
    import { Collection } from './Products';
    export interface IAppProps {}
    export interface IAppState {
      showDetails: boolean;
    }

    const collectionInstance = new Collection();
    class App extends React.Component<IAppProps, IAppState> {
      constructor(props: IAppProps) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.state = { showDetails: false };
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <CollectionView {...collectionInstance} />
          </div>
        );
      }
      handleClick() {
        console.log(`App.handleClick() called`);
        this.setState({
          showDetails: !this.state.showDetails,
        });
      }
    }


    export default App;
```

```js
    import { Box } from '@material-ui/core';
    import React from 'react';
    import { ItemView } from './ItemView';
    import { Collection } from './Products';

    export class CollectionView extends React.Component<Collection> {
      constructor(props: Collection) {
        super(props);
        this.handlerItemClicked = this.handlerItemClicked.bind(this);
      }
       handlerItemClicked(id: number) {
        console.log(`handlerItemClick:${id}`);
        this.props.handlerItemClicked(id);
      }
      render() {
        let items = this.props.items.map((item) => {
          return (
            <ItemView
              {...item}
              key={item.id}
              onItemClicked={this.handlerItemClicked}
            />
          );
        });
        return (
          <Box display='flex' flexWrap='wrap'>
            {items}
          </Box>
        );
      }
    }
```

```js
    import { AppBar, Dialog, IconButton, Slide, Toolbar } from '@material-ui/core';
    import { TransitionProps } from '@material-ui/core/transitions/transition';
    import { Close } from '@material-ui/icons';
    import React from 'react';
    import { IProduct } from './Products';

    export interface IDetailsProps {
      open: boolean;
      product: IProduct | null;
      handleClose(): void;
    }

    const Transition = React.forwardRef(function Transition(
      props: TransitionProps & { children?: React.ReactElement },
      ref: React.Ref<unknown>,
    ) {
      return <Slide direction='left' ref={ref} {...props} />;
    });
    export class DetailView extends React.Component<IDetailsProps> {
      constructor(props: IDetailsProps) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div className='full-screen-details-dialogue'>
            <Dialog
              fullScreen
              open={this.props.open}
              TransitionComponent={Transition}>
              <AppBar>
                <Toolbar>
                  <IconButton
                    edge='start'
                    color='inherit'
                    onClick={this.handleClose}
                    aria-label='close'>
                    <Close></Close>
                  </IconButton>
                </Toolbar>
              </AppBar>
            </Dialog>
          </div>
        );
      }
      handleClose() {
        console.log(`Details:handleClose()`);
        this.props.handleClose();
      }
    }
```

```js
    import { InputBaseClassKey } from '@material-ui/core';

    export interface IProduct {
      id: number;
      name: string;
      type: string;
      image: string;
      longDescription: string;
      specs?: ISpecs;
    }
    export interface ISpecs {
      actuationForce: string;
      actuationPoint: string;
      bottomOut: string;
      bottomOutTravel: string;
      price: string;
    }
    export class Collection {
       items: IProduct[] = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Holy Panda',
          type: 'Tactile',
          image:
            'https://ih0.redbubble.net/image.618638614.1485/raf,750x1000,075,t,fafafa:ca443f4786.jpg',
          longDescription: '...',
          specs: {
            actuationForce: '44',
            actuationPoint: '2.4',
            bottomOut: '62',
            bottomOutTravel: '3.8',
            price: '1.60',
          },
        },
      ];
      handlerItemClicked(_id: number) {}
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript [transpiles](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqBOBLAptA3gWAFDWgC0gAoB3Ae3gBMBKdaeZAFwFd4A7aB%20J5AbmgF9sgrNlCQYCFACZ02XARgBeaCXLVoigHwcuvIdiA) classes in such a way that class methods are bound to the `prototype` of the class, not instances of that class. Creating a new object with spread syntax (`{...collectionInstance}`) does not copy those methods to the new object because [spread syntax only copies own & enumerable properties](https://dmitripavlutin.com/object-rest-spread-properties-javascript/#12ownproperties).

You need to bind the function `handlerItemClicked` to the class instance by changing your class definition. The easiest way to do this is to simply replace the method declaration with an arrow function, which automatically binds that function to the class instances.

```
export class Collection {
  // etc
  handlerItemClicked = (_id: number) => {}
}
```

[This](https://www.sung.codes/blog/2019/spread-syntax-gotcha-in-javascript-class-methods) was a very helpful blog post explaining this gotcha. I found it by googling "javascript spread class instance". I had a hunch it had something to do with binding scope, but did not understand the details of this particular case until finding that article.

Answer (score -1):

Tnx jered,it's solved problem for me. Actually I thought that already bind the function using syntax

```js
this.handlerItemClicked = this.handlerItemClicked.bind(this);
```

but obviously not.A reed that arrow function bind method itself and this is the perfect example. Thx again.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment.